# Idiomatic way to register custom Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My use case is that I'm using Spring Security 5.2's Oauth2 login, but would like my database user class to be available alongside the Oauth2AuthenticationToken within the Authentication. This is so that I have my database user class cached by the SecurityContextHolder.

In Pseudocode:

1. A user logs in using Google or Github Oauth2
2. My app finds (or creates) the database user with the information returned
3. My app saves to the SecurityContextHolder a custom Authentication wrapper that wraps both the Oauth2AuthenticationToken and the database User class
4. On subsequent requests, the custom Authentication wrapper is available to controller methods

Here are my attempts at a wrapper:

```
class MyAuthenticationWrapper implements Authentication {

        public MyAuthenticationWrapper(User user, Authentication underlyingAuth1) {
            this.user = user;
            this.underlyingAuth = underlyingAuth1;
        }

        private final User user;
        private final Authentication underlyingAuth;

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return underlyingAuth.getAuthorities();
        }

        @Override
        public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) {
            underlyingAuth.setAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return underlyingAuth.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCredentials() {
            return underlyingAuth.getCredentials();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPrincipal() {
            return underlyingAuth.getPrincipal();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return underlyingAuth.isAuthenticated();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getDetails() {
            return underlyingAuth.getDetails();
        }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And a custom Oauth2AuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
class CustomLoginAuthenticationFilter extends OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    Authentication auth = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    if (auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        switch (((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) auth).authorizedClientRegistrationId) {
            case "google":
                Optional<User> user = userDAO.findByEmail(username);
                if (!user.isPresent()) {
                    throw new NotFoundException("!");
                }
                return MyAuthenticationWrapper(auth, user.get());
            }
        }
        return auth;
    }
}
```

I haven't had success getting this approach to work, and I'm left wondering if this is the right approach at all.

Is there another, more idiomatic approach to combining database user data with Oauth2 user data in Spring security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps looking into `OAuth2UserService` might help. It gets invoked after successfully obtaining the OAuth token. This is how it would work:

> 1. A user logs in using Google or Github Oauth2

No need to add anything. Let the default filters take care of that.

> 2. My app finds (or creates) the database user with the information returned

Create your own `OAuth2UserService` as a bean (it'll get picked up automatically) that takes care of dealing with the database:

```
@Component
public class CustomService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest)
        throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        // ... DB logic goes here
    }
}
```

In `loadUser(...)`, the `OAuth2UserRequest` gives you access to the corresponding `ClientRegistration` and the `OAuth2AccessToken`, which you can then use to query or update the database.

> 3. My app saves to the SecurityContextHolder a custom Authentication wrapper that wraps both the Oauth2AuthenticationToken and the database User class

No need to deal with a wrapper! The custom `OAuth2User` you construct from information from the database will be the `Principal` in the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken`, which ends up being the `Authentication`, so it'll be available to your application. Since you're not dealing with the `Authentication` yourself, you wouldn't have to worry about saving it in the `SecurityContextHolder`.

> 4. On subsequent requests, the custom Authentication wrapper is available to controller methods

Your `Authentication` will be of type `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken`. You can get your custom `OAuth2User` like this:

```
OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken auth = //...
OAuth2User user = auth.getPrincipal();
```

**For more info** on the core classes you're dealing with, these might be helpful:

- [`OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java)
- [`OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java)
- [`OAuth2UserRequest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/userinfo/OAuth2UserRequest.java)
- [`OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.java)

**For out-of-the-box** implementations of `OAuth2UserService`, check out:

- [`DefaultOAuth2UserService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/userinfo/DefaultOAuth2UserService.java)
- [`CustomUserTypesOAuth2UserService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/userinfo/CustomUserTypesOAuth2UserService.java)

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer and for pointing me to OAuth2UserService. Half of using Spring is knowing the right class to override!

Comment: @NatFar In OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter the following code block fetches the authorizationRequest from the session.
what if I don't want to use the session? I would like to implement stateless JWT authentication.

after fetching the access token and validating it, I want to generate a JWT token, and set it to the response header and then I will redirect it to my UI app.
so it seems that I need to customize OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter do you have any idea?

Comment: @NarFar the code block I mention on the previous message is :
`OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestRepository
  .removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
if (authorizationRequest == null) {
 OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE);
 throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
}`